# Programming language with these criteria

Tags: dynamic, programming-languages, properties, components

I need a programming language (preferably scriptable and having JIT would be a plus, but these two are not necessary), which would allow something like this (example):

```
object
{
     id;
     new();
     destroy();
}

info
{
     descr;
}

event inherit object, info
{
     trigger; //has id, descr, trigger
}

anon_event inherit event
{
     - decr; //removes descr property, therefore anon_event has id, trigger, but NO descr  
}
```

It would be especially nice, that it could also:

- autogenerate id's on creation(new()),
- allow specify which properties(members) are read public, private, const
- autogenerate getters/setters for public properties (getters for const),
- have logging/callback facilities for getters/setters,
- allow select on property (selectallprop(descr) would select all instances with descr property) and on type selectalltype(event) would select all events and anon_events even if the members are not the same,
- allow runtime inheritance, addition/removal of properties;

I think this is enough to give a general idea what type of language I am seeking. Basically, it's a component(list of properties as component members) based or looking from another point of view multiple inheritance without common ancestor.

Thank you for your tips

Comment: Your example means nothing to me. Perhaps you should instead **explain** what you want.

Comment: instances of anon_event do not have descr member (anon_event foo; foo.descr -> "desc" results in an error, selectallprop(descr) does not return foo inside the returned list).

Comment: Another example, this time from reality. Consider human race: some properties are common: mammal, breathes-air, some properties are common: two arms, two legs, a head. Later are not necessary to call somebody a human, but previous currently are. One can't enumerate all properties of a human. It is impossible because of a genotype mutation which leads to constantly changing fenotype. Therefore it is necessary an object to be a type of human but lose/gain properties during runtime(evolution). Even necessary properties might evolve during long evolution.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for would (1) violate the Liskov Substitution Principle, an important tenet of object-oriented programming, and (2) would be almost impossible to use in practice, as removing arbitrary members from a class will very often lead to non-compiling or non-functional code as other members in that same class would much of the time depend on those removed members.

So what I'm saying is: this whole thing is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my idea, my object does (should not) represent a specific class/type of object but rather a component(holder of properties), which should be inheritable for convenience. I do not expect that its behavior should be limited like in real OOP. I think, VM could track all properties and types of components and e.g. generating exceptions on invalid access. Therefore selectallprop would be useful to limit such cases. Object would be accessed only if it has such a property, function, or is a type of some class.